# How can I use a dual 4-channel analog multiplexer independently?

Tags: digital-logic, resistors, multiplexer, dual

I have a CD4529BCN Dual 4-Channel Analog Data Selector ([datasheet](http://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/-5499058989021646423)).
Here is the truth table:

[image: Truth Table]

Here is the problem:
I have two sensors which are resistive. I want to read their voltage via a resistive-divider and a buffer. I want to switch 4 different resistors for **each** resistor-divider circuit.
According to the truth table (in dual mode), when I choose say resistor X1 to be attached to Z, Y1 would be automatically attached to W. But I want independent behavior.
How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: Use two separate chips, or look for a chip that containsn two 4-1 mux with independent address pins. I don't recall any bsuch chips in the CD4xxxx series, but they might exist, maybe outside that series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you normally wouldn't use a multiplexer at all. Because there's no need for signal multiplexing – you just need to switch resistors in and out of your divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0vzPf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How you implement the four switches depends on the supply voltage and on the magnitude of the resistors we're talking about – if R_sensor + R1…R4 is something like kΩ, and your supply voltage is let's say 9V, then, by all means, use a simple tri-state 8bit shift register to pull exactly one of the four R's outputs down, and leave the rest floating. Account for the voltage drop in the shift register.

If we're talking several Ω, implementing each SW with a low-r_dsOn MOSFET might be the better alternative. You could, again, easily control these directly with some IO pins, or with a shift register. BJTs might also be a good alternative.

Another pretty intuitive option: There's digitally controllable resistors. They work pretty well for low-frequency and DC applications. You can program them to have a specific resistance.

Yet another option: what you're actually doing by changing the R is changing the current through your sensing resistor. So why don't you simply build an adjustable current source? There's different ways of doing that, but if you need low component count and high accuracy: there's current-source DACs designed exactly for such measurement jobs.

Comment: Marcus, That is exactly my application circuit! R_sensor is actually a Force Sensitive Resistor (FSR) and it's range is between several Ohms and several MOhms. I've actually designed and tested one circuit with digPot but they are very expensive and its range is 10k... You have provided lots of ideas . Thanks. I don't know how to build a controllable current source though...

Comment: as said, you don't have to. Buy a current DAC. They make so many of these, they actually sell them :) Digital value goes in, current comes out.

Comment: One thing, What is wrong with using Mux? Is there any advantage in using Shift Register to using Mux?

Comment: you're not muxing a signal; muxes are designed to be as linear to the input signal as possible, not to exhibit minimal resistance. Whether or not that is a problem depends on your signal and the buffer.

Comment: Also, price mux > price shift register, usually, but that's not generally true.

Comment: Here, by the way: DACs that convert digital value to current from [Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/data-converters/dac-circuit/products.html#p116=Buffered%20Current;Unbuffered%20Current). Use http://octopart.com to find cheap sources.

Comment: About the shift register idea, sn74hc595 has a /oe pin which makes **all** outputs in tristate. How can I leave the individual pin floating with a shift register? Or did you mean outputs of the shift register control gate of transistors connecting resistors to ground?

Comment: then that is not the shift register you want. I don't have shift register types in my head, sorry.

Comment: I've searched the net, people are suggesting to use CPLD or using two shift registers but design would be complex in that scenario

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree, CPLDs would be quite overkill here. So use any shift register and logic-level MOSFETs. Or really, go for the current-DAC solution :)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one set of address pins, they are common to both internal sections, and they are not latched.  Because of that, this part cannot do what you want.  There are many 4:1 mux parts with varying levels of performance.

What is the minimum external resistor value being switched?

What is the highest mux internal resistance you can tolerate?

Comment: Min extRes is 2k and I don't care about the mux internal resistance . I've done some tests and it is currently varying between 320 Ohm (for R_ext 10k) and 404 OHm (for R_ext 560 Ohm)